# Обособление уточнений

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Допустим, есть предложение:

Наш сотрудник Иванов Алексей дал подробное объяснение случившемуся.

Считается ли имя сотрудника уточнением? Стоит ли его выделять запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о рядовом сотруднике и персоналия здесь не главное, то да, уточнение, которое логично обособить, а то и заключить в скобки.
Но скорее всего здесь имеется в виду непосредственный участник каких-то событий или руководитель, ответственное лицо, дающее пояснение по своей должности. Тогда обособление не только не требуется, но и невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Это приложение. Оно не выделяется запятыми. Но автор вправе оформить имя и как уточнение, это даст другую интонацию.